# Mathematica Semilog (LogLinearPlot) using x,y points from table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to use the LogLinearPlot in Mathematica 9 to create an x-axis only logarithmic plot that looks like this (Based on N^1.85 graphing paper) http://pingfire.com/

What it does is model a curve for theoretical residual pressures and their corresponding expected flow rates in gallons per minute (based on exponential friction loss in water moving through piping), but the graph paper displays this in a straight line format that is easier to interpret values from.

It appears that LogLinearPlot is what I am looking for, but the samples show it using a function of x, not a list of x,y points. How do I plug in a table of x,y points into the LogLinearPlot function?

Here is an example from pingfire.com showing the straight line I'm trying to get from two points (Static pressure which is x,y of 0,80 and residual pressure which is x,y of 900,40)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpUZ1.png

Using that image, you can interpolate what the pressure/flow will be at any gpm on the graph (100 to 1000), for example, 31 pressure at 1000 gpm (the end of the graph)

Comment: `ListLogLinearPlot`...

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLogLinearPlot.html

these appear not to be straight lines

Comment: ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{0, 80}, {900, 40}], Joined -> True]

does not seem to be working??

Comment: Um, that depends on the data. As for your second comment, why would it do anything but plot the one point you've specified (along with the arguments are completely wrong).

Comment: `ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{0, 80}, {900, 40}], Joined -> True]` doesn't work for two reasons: the `Table` syntax is nonsense (refer to the documentation), and in a loglinear plot you can't have zeros.

Comment: To the closers: most of the answers are easily found in the documentation, but using a different log base in plotting is not.

Answer (score 0):

See, e.g.:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{x, Log[x]}, {x, 1, 100}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: what about the N^1.85 part? is there a way to specify the log base as being 1.85?

Comment: also how do you add the y coordinates?

Comment: @user3111684: Please update your OP with the code you're trying, and the result. This is not a "do my work for me" site, it is a place to get help with attempts/problems/issues with implementing things in MM.

Comment: I didn't ask you to do it for me, I asked how. Instructions, not pictures. This is a question and answer site, not a question and complain about the question site.

Comment: @user3111684:MM has excellent and copious documentation. Refer to it, make an attempt, and if you still have problems post the code and results.